# Creating a google map GUI

Tags: javascript, image, google-maps

i want to have a Google map like system (preferably in java script) which i could apply to an image in a div like this

```
    <div id="map">
        <img src="example/src.jpg" alt="map" id="mapImg"/>
    </div>
```

and i wanted it to be able to give me the zoom in and out and pan in directions functionality, i was wondering how i would go about this. i am new to Java script. i have a high res image i plan on using to do this.i have not tried much to be honest and i have seen many JQuery plugins for it but i want a purely java script version which would be easily implemented to pan and zoom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes Google Maps API v3 has an option called [**Image Map Types**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#ImageMapTypes), in which you have an custom-image with pan and zoom tools.

Here check out this [**example**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image).

Comment: is there nothing simpler, i am relatively new to Java Script and this is kind of a start up project :) if not I'm sure I can get to learn the Google API version.

Comment: @Kieranmv95 AFIK, this is the most simplest way to perform..  because pan tools and zoom tools are provided by Google API... You can check the example given in the answer.